# How to write to specific cells in an existing Excel (xlsc) file with C#

Tags: c#, excel, cell

I managed to read from an Excel file using IExcelDataReader, now I wish to write to specific cells in an existing Excel file, so I need to specify path to the file, column and row where the data should be inserted. I googled and found some examples but there were disputes whether the solutions worked or not. So which is the simplest way of doing this (code examples appriciated). Thanks.

Edit: So I tried doing this:

```
Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open("Path", 0, true, 5,"", "", true,     Excel.xlWindows, "\t", false, false,0, true);
```

But get the type or namespace name "Application" does not exist in the namespace Excel.
And the same for "Workbook".

I added the references Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Office. What more do I need?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following should sort out your namespace issues:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

To write to a cell you can use the following (assuming you already have a `Worksheet` object):

```
xlWorksheet.Cells["1", "A"] = "Foo";
```

This is the method I've been using for a couple of years and it's worked without fail every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try doing this using some rpa tool such as G1ANT. 
It will make your work much easy.
Try this simple code for updating cell:

```
addon xlsx version 4.101.0.0
addon core version 4.101.0.0
addon language version 4.103.0.0
xlsx.open C:\Documents\TestBook.xlsx createifnotexist true
xlsx.setvalue value 123 row 1 colname a
xlsx.close
```